# Get all the edges from a set of vertexes

Tags: gremlin

I am new to Gremlin and am trying to list all the edges that connect a set of nodes:

```
const vertexes = g.V().where(...).toList()
[1]
[2]
[4]
```

I want to retrieve all the edges that connect [1],[2] and [4] excluding all the other edges.

For the moment, I wrote the following:

```
g.V(vertexes).bothE().dedup().toList()
```

But this command will return all the edges from and to the selected vertexes including edges coming and going to other not selected vertexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to filter the edges by the adjacent vertex:

```
gremlin> g.V(1,2,3).bothE().dedup().where(otherV().hasId(1,2,3))
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
```

You can read more about these sorts of patterns in the TinkerPop [Gremlin Recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#between-vertices).